# How to enable certain (not all) monolog handlers for production?

Tags: symfony, production-environment, monolog

I have a symfony2 application, which has a bunch of monolog handlers in place. The logging for the dev environment works fine, yet I want one monolog handler to be always be logging, naming `transmission_recorder`, also on prod. Yet for the prod, the logging is inactive.

I am assuming that the `finger_crossed` might prevent logging on prod, yet I do not want to enable logging of all the things for all the monolog handlers, only for a specific one.

How do I achieve that?

Here's my relevant configuration:

`config.yml`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        console:
            type: console
        transmission_recorder:
            type: service
            id: dba.handler.transmission.recorder
```

`config_dev.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   rotating_file
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
            max_files: 14
            channels:
                - "!event"
        console:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
```

`config_prod.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: WARNING
            handler:      grouped_warning
        grouped_warning:
            type: group
            members:
                - file_debug
        file_debug:
            type:  rotating_file
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            max_files: 14
        console:
            type:  console
```

Comment: Have you ever figured it out?